# Is this expression idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I want to ask my colleague till what time he is supposed to work here, and what is latest time has has worked at office, Can I ask him

> What is the latest have you worked here?

Is this expression idiomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although that sentence would probably be understood by your colleague, it is not particularly idiomatic. Instead the following would be preferable:

> What is the latest you've ever left the office?

Or

> I once stayed in the office until 8pm! What's the latest you've ever stayed 'til?

Comment: So problem is with the verb work/leave/stay? not with the use of latest, right?

Comment: @Tim: *Latest* is fine in this context. The problem is really with the fragment "have you worked here", which is usually heard in the context of "How long have you worked here?" meaning "How long have you been working for this company?", which then doesn't sit well with the fact that the question is asking about the latest time the person has ever left the office on any particular occasion.

Comment: _How late have you stayed?_ might also work. But I like both of Matt's suggestions quite a bit.